# Integration By Parts of $A_n(x)$ with Solution in Terms of $A_{n-2}(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

Let $$A_n(x)=\int x^n\sin(4x)$$ and $$v'=\sin(4x)$$

Using Integration by Parts, we get $$A_n(x)=-\frac{x^n\cos(4x)}{4}+\int\frac{nx^{n-1}\cos(4x)}{4}$$

Using Integration by Parts on this new integral,  and letting$$v'=\frac{\cos(4x)}{4}$$we get $$A_n(x)=-\frac{x^n\cos(4x)}{4}+\frac{nx^{n-1}\sin(4x)}{16}+!!!\int\frac{\sin(4x)(n-1)nx^{n-2}}{16}!!!$$

I'm fairly sure that this is alright so far (the first two fractions are being shown as correct), but the problem is that the submission system requires the last integral (between the !!!'s) to be calculated and in the form of $$(integral solution)A_{n-2}(x)$$ 
I'm pretty much stuck at this point, calculating the integral with two variables isn't something I've done before, and so far none of my attempts have worked.

Please note that the $A_{n-2}(x)$ at the very end is hardcoded into the submission, so the answer needs to be in that format.

Comment: You can take $n(n-1)/16$ out of the integration sign, $=\frac{n(n-1)}{16}A_{n-2}$

Comment: @Nikunj That got me to $$-\frac{n(n-1)}{16}4\cos(x)\frac{x^(n-1)}{n-1}$$ but that's still wrong. The question almost seems like my answer should be multiplied by $A_{n-2}$, but I don't really know.

Comment: $$\int\frac{\sin(4x)(n-1)nx^{n-2}dx}{16}=\frac{n(n-1)}{16}\int x^{n-2}\sin 4x dx=\frac{n(n-1)}{16}A_{n-2}$$ I'm sorry I can't explain any better than this.

Comment: All good. I had tried what you said originally but it was still wrong, so I just wanted to confirm. Chances are it's just the submission being annoying, because that should be right.

Comment: Just commenting to say that the answer was accepted when I threw a negative at the front. Makes sense since the formula normally has a negative, but they wrote it with a plus.
@Nikunj Feel free to put your comment up as an answer if you want the rep.

Comment: glad I could help.